# Node pattern for promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, asynchronous, promise

I have a node issue. I want to call a Data Access Object and possibly other within it and once completed render a Jade template

Something like :

```
 provider1.getData(args, function(error, results) {

   /* do something with each result element */
   for(int i = 0l i < results.length; i++) {
     provider2.getData(args, function(error, items) {

        store.push(items);
     });
   }
 });
 /* Here I want to ensure that the above operations are complete */
 result.render( .... , {
   data:store
 });
```

Basically, I want to ensure that the data retrieval completes before I render a template with the data. At the moment, the variable store is not populated when the render occurs. I have looked at `promises` which looks promising. Does anyone have a neat solution for converting my code example into a synchronous structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) library.

```
provider1.getData(args, function(error, results) {

   /* do something with each result element */
   async.each(results,
                       function(result, cb) { // called for each item in results
                           provider2.getData(args, function(error, items) {

                                  store.push(items);
                                  cb(error);
                            });
                       },
                       // final callback
                       function (err) {
                           if (!err) {
                             /* Here I want to ensure that the above operations are complete */
                              result.render( .... , {
                                     data:store
                               });
                           }
                       }
                    );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a promises answer (assuming [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)). I think it's a lot cleaner:

```
// convert to promise interface, it's possible to do this on a single method basis
// or an API basis, it depends on your case - it's also _very_ fast. 
Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(provider1.prototype)); 
Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(provider2.prototype));

//note the async suffix is added by promisification.
provider1.getDataAsync(args).then(function(results) {
   return Promise.map(results,provider2.getDataAsync.bind(provider2));
}).then(function(results){
    //results array here, everything is done and ready,
});
```

As always with promises, if you have an error you can simply `throw`.